# Get the downloading Multiple Files Automatically parameter in Google Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, download

I want to download automatically multiple files in my website in Chrome. But the downloading will not work if the Chrome setting 'Automatic download' is blocked.
So I want to know if there is a way to know the value of the 'Automatic download' in Chrome settings in Javascript ? (Authorized, blocked, or 'ask')

Thanks